# Unable to find maven dependency on own nexus

Tags: java, maven, bitbucket, nexus

I recently set up my own nexus repository oss, but now I am struggling to use it.

I configured my projects so that the bitbucket-pipelines would directly deploy my software after I pushed it to the repository. That seemed to work: At least I can see my projects, if I browse my nexus repository.

The problem is: My other projects cant resolve the dependency. Maybe I am missing something in my maven settings.xml or my pom.xml itself? I dont know.

Would be nice, if someone could lend me a helping hand.

I will provide my settings.xml and my pom.xml - please be aware that I replaced my real server paths and some other information by dummy-information. I hope this will be no problem.

First my settings.xml

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>
> <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
>           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>           xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
>
>   <pluginGroups>
>   </pluginGroups>
>   <proxies>
>   </proxies>
>   <servers>
>   <server>
>       <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
>       <username>dummy-user-name</username>
>       <password>abc123!</password>
>   </server>
>       <server>
>       <id>nexus-releases</id>
>       <username>dummy-user-name</username>
>       <password>abc123!</password>
>   </server>
>   </servers>
>   <mirrors>
>      -->
>       <mirror>
>           <id>nexus</id>
>           <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
>           <url>http://dummy-server-url:8081/repository/maven-central/</url>
>       </mirror>
>   </mirrors>
>
>   <profiles>
>       <profile>
>       <id>nexus</id>
>       <repositories>
>         <repository>
>           <id>central</id>
>           <url>http://central</url>
>           <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
>           <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
>         </repository>
>       </repositories>
>      <pluginRepositories>
>         <pluginRepository>
>           <id>central</id>
>           <url>http://central</url>
>           <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
>           <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
>         </pluginRepository>
>       </pluginRepositories>
>     </profile>
>   </profiles>
>
>     <activeProfiles>
>     <!--make the profile active all the time -->
>     <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
>   </activeProfiles>
> </settings>
> ```

My pom.xml

> http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>       4.0.0
>
> ```
> <groupId>some.group.id</groupId>
> <artifactId>someArtifactID</artifactId>
> <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>
> <properties>
>     <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
>     <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
> </properties>
>
> <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>some.group.ide</groupId>
>         <artifactId>Other</artifactId>
>         <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>     </dependency>
> </dependencies>
>
> <!-- Konfiguration, welche den Pfad zum Nexus angibt. -->
> <distributionManagement>
>     <snapshotRepository>
>         <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
>         <url>http://dummy-server-url.net:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
>     </snapshotRepository>
> </distributionManagement>
>
> <build>
>     <plugins>
>         <!-- Das Standardplugin wird hier deaktiviert. Möglicherweise fehlt hier noch Version -->
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>             <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
>             <configuration>
>                 <skip>true</skip>
>             </configuration>
>         </plugin>
>         <!-- Wir definieren hier das Nexus-Plugin-->
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
>             <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>1.3</version>
>             <executions>
>                 <execution>
>                     <id>default-deploy</id>
>                     <phase>deploy</phase>
>                     <goals>
>                         <goal>deploy</goal>
>                     </goals>
>                 </execution>
>             </executions>
>             <configuration>
>                 <serverId>nexus</serverId>
>                 <nexusUrl>http://dummy-server-url.net:8081/nexus/</nexusUrl>
>                 <skipStaging>true</skipStaging>
>             </configuration>
>         </plugin>
>
>         <plugin>
>             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>3.1</version>
>             <configuration>
>                 <source>1.8</source>
>                 <target>1.8</target>
>                 <verbose>true</verbose>
>                 <fork>true</fork>
>             </configuration>
>         </plugin>
>
>     </plugins>
> </build> </project>
> ```

My IntelliJ always marks my 1.0-SNAPSHOT red and tells me I would be unable to find the dependency.
The resolver-status.properties-File in my .m2-directory just tells me

> Return code is: 400 , ReasonPhrase:Repository version policy:
>   RELEASE does not allow metadata in path:
>   dev/derektar/Common/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml

I search the internet for a while but I wasnt able to find a solution. Maybe because I am not very experienced administrating my own nexus and building with maven. Until a few days ago I just had to develop software and never had to care about these things. Due to that I would be very thankful if someone could help me out.

If this is a stupid question, I am really sorry for that.

Kind regards.

Comment: Looks like you got confugration for release version insteed of snapshots

Comment: Do you still have that error when you disable `nexus-staging-maven-plugin` (and re-enable `maven-deploy-plugin`)? It looks like maven tries to deploy a snapshot version of your artefact to a release repo.

Comment: Where can I check this?

In my nexus repo, I can find the 1.0-SNAPSHOT-Folder under maven-snapshots.

I seems to me the build works correctly, but I cant get the depedency from the nexus.

Comment: I just tried to deploy the artifact from my intelliJ directly. In this case the dependency can be found. My IntelliJ ist using the same settings.xml and the same pom.xml as the bitbucket-repo does.
So the problem seem to be that maven cant read that thing from nexus oss. I really dont now why.

Comment: @Antonioussss is right unless you changed the default "Maven-Central" repository is for Release artifacts.  You can see this under "Version Policy".  You should be able to get this working by creating a group, putting the requisite repos in it and pointing your sources there.  See https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Maven+Repositories#MavenRepositories-GroupingMavenRepositories.  I left a comment rather than an answer because I feel credit belongs to Antoniossss.

Comment: The nexus default installation comes with a pre-configured configuration which contains a group and two hosted repos maven-releases and maven-snapshots. I checked that configuration and it was okay.
So I choosed to configure the whole "workspace" and the settings.xml from zero. Now it works.

Thank you very very much for your comments!!! I really appreciate it